# Thread STA mode issue to open file explorer openFileDialog.ShowDialog() (C#)

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, showdialog

I've been looking everywhere to find where the issue could come from, but nothing.

Basically when I run the program, coming to this point where it should open the windows file explorer, it does not.

One code editor when running it, showed me that :

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'The current thread must be in STA (Single Thread Apartment) mode before OLE calls can be made. Make sure your Main is marked as STAThreadAttribute. This exception is only triggered if a debugger is attached to the process'.

I used STAThread though.

Here is my code :

```
        [STAThread]
        public static void Settings()
        {
            var filePath = string.Empty;   
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write(" Upload :");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                    openFileDialog.Title = "Upload";
                    openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files|*.txt";
                    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
                    openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
                }while (!File.Exists(filePath));
                filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciate.
Thank you !

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(500)`? Why would you do that?

Comment: The [STAThread] attribute only works on the entrypoint of the program, Main()

Comment: The sleep is sensible, give the user a chance to read the message before overlapping it with the dialog.  There are additional requirements.  Dialogs always need an owner window, one they can stay on top of.  Doubtful that this colorful console can act like one.  Consequence is that the dialog can get behind another window with no taskbar button to get back to it.  And an STAThread is a *promise*, you say you'll run a dispatcher loop with Application.Run(). Consequence of a needy shell extension is that the program may deadlock.

Comment: @AluanHaddad To give the user a small time to read the message "Please upload your list" before overlapping the dialog

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot first for answering. I've tried deleteing the colorful console and the sleep, but still having the same issue. I think it comes as you said from your first comment : only works at the entrypoint of the program.

Comment: I've edited the code by rewriting it indepently with Micorosft's template, but still does not want to open